# How to set default time as local time for any created folder or files in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

In my web application I am creating folders and files dynamically, while creating Folder/Files `CreatedDate` or `ModifiedDate` is taking as Server Time..

I want to set `CreatedDate` or `ModifiedDate` as my local time..
how to do this..

My code for creating folders

```csharp
DirectoryInfo dirDptFolder = new DirectoryInfo(strDptRoot);
if (dirDptFolder.Exists == false)
{
    dirDptFolder.Create();
}
```

Comment: i dont want to change in server, i want to set local time zone for particular Application..

Comment: Look for code sample here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcreationtime.aspx. Also check other functions of Directory class at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx..

Answer (score 2):

**The server creation time is the same as your local time**

If your clocks are up to date, the creation time on the server will be the same time as your local time.

It may seem different because you may be located in different time zones.

The best way to think of it is that all times are saved as UTC. They are displayed to the local time depending on your time zone settings in your OS.

You can get the actual file creation time in UTC like so:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);  
creationTimeUTC = file.CreationTimeUtc;
Console.WriteLine("The files creation time in UTC: {0}", file.CreationTimeUtc);
```

If your local machine is using Central Standard Time then you could convert the files creation time on the server to display as CST time like so:

```
TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(file.CreationTimeUtc, cstZone);
Console.WriteLine("The files creation time in CST: {0}", cstTime);
```

Therefore it is not necessary to change the creation time on the server to your local time, files are always saved as UTC.

If you want the server time to be exactly the same as your local time, either change your servers TimeZone to match that of your local machine or visa versa.

Comment: No, the creation time is UTC, not the local time.  And it is not recommended to use the `TimeZone` class anymore, but rather `TimeZoneInfo`.  There is no `Date` type in C#.  `CreationTimeUtc` is a property, not a method.  And you're just converting back to local time anyway, so you might as well just use `CreationTime` property which already has that.  So in short, this answer doesn't compile and doesn't get you anywhere.

Comment: Thats what I said - the creation time is in UTC! The other stuff is just an example to try to help you understand that there is no difference in time - the difference is the time zone.

Comment: That was in regards to the first sentence of your answer.  And I'm not sure what you mean "the difference is the time zone".  Your answer still doesn't compile.

Comment: The user wanted to know how to change the time of the file on the remote 'Server' to be the same as the time on their 'Local' machine. I was explaining that it is not the file creation time that is different , but the timezone of the machines.

Comment: he clearly states it is a 'web application' and he wants the file/folder creation time on the server to be the same as his local time.

Comment: Ok, got that last part. I missed the asp.net tag in the question.  But it is still not the same as his "local time".  I think what you are saying is that the UTC time of the server is the same as the UTC time anywhere as long as the clocks are in sync.  But his local time is probably not UTC, so your answer is still misleading.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38991/discussion-between-matt-johnson-and-geo1701)

Comment: I'm sure we both have better things to do :)

Answer (score 0):

What if different users have different time zones? How about just converting to user time when displaying the data to the users? :)

You can either ask the user to input their timezone or detect it using javascript and store it in a cookie. there are various ways to do this, but here is one script that can do it https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect

cookies can also be saved in a variety of ways, but I like jquery.
http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

You can then read the cookie on the server side and use the methods others have mentioned to convert your times to that timezone.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: Op is trying to save files with created dates of users. This wont be consistent(most likely). A better solution would be use server time and convert to user time when displaying the data. How is this not an answer?

Comment: I see two sentences both with question marks. If you meant to recommend that solution, then you should show an example of how it could be done.

Comment: Are you serious? a downvote because of grammar? Not to mention its more or less the same approach as you yourself recommend? [converting on display] Downvoting people who give the same answer as you is not very cool.

Comment: Put something more useful in your answer and I will remove the downvote.

Comment: Added tips on how to get timezones

Answer (score 0):

As long as your file system is NTFS, then file times are always stored as UTC.

If you look at the implementation of `System.IO.FileInfo.CreationTime`, you will see the following:

```
public DateTime CreationTime
{
  get
  {
    return this.CreationTimeUtc.ToLocalTime();
  }
  set
  {
    this.CreationTimeUtc = value.ToUniversalTime();
  }
}
```

As you can see, it's a wrapper around `CreationTimeUtc`, just converted to the local time for convenience.  The `LastWriteTime` and `LastAccessTime` properties work the same way.

So, you can't change a file to be stamped with a different time zone, because they are never stamped with the local time of any particular time zone to begin with.  They are stamped in UTC.

If you want to convert that to some *other* time zone, then do it on the way out when you read it.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);  
DateTime utc = fi.CreationTimeUtc;
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime eastern = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, tzi);
```

Note, there are similar methods off of the `System.IO.File` class, such as `File.GetCreationTimeUtc()`, which essentially do the same thing.  Use whichever you are comfortable with.

Also note, this is *not* the case for FAT/FAT32 file systems.  For those file systems, the server's local timestamp is used.  Taking a file from one location to another could lead to misinterpreting the timestamp.

Comment: Thats is exactly what I said and you marked my answer down! wtf!

Comment: @geo1701 I marked your answer down because you recommended `TimeZone` class, and your code does not compile.  My code does compile, and shows using a specific time zone.  The proper response is to edit your code, not to downvote mine.  I will remove my downvote when your response is accurate.

Comment: I updated my answer to make it clearer - it don't think it is misleading I do agree that code should compile :)